# Checking Variables against a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok, I've had a look around but since the word 'dictionary' already has meaning in Python then I'm struggling. I am referring to the Oxford (or others) English Dictionary.

I have an array (list) of words. I want to loop though them and check if each one is in the English dictionary. If it is I want to increase a variable by 1.

This is all very simple apart from the 'getting Python to read a dictionary' which I'm not sure about. I have found a .txt dictionary which I could use but the words are in there with definitions making it impossible to pick out the actual words.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Comment: Get a better wordlist file. If you do a something search for "English word list" you should find results immediately.

Comment: Without knowing the format of the .txt dictionary you found, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Nsh how on earth is it difficult to tell what I'm asking? Which part exactly did you struggle with and I'll help you out?

Comment: If you just need a list with words that are in the dictionary, but not their meaning, you can use [`words`](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords), a standard file on all Unix and Unix-like operating systems that is simply a newline-delimited list of dictionary words. It is used, for instance, by spell-checking programs. The words file is usually stored in `/usr/share/dict/words`, or `/usr/dict/words`.

Comment: Khelwood, so is using the wordlist file the only way I can do it. There's no built in functionality in Python for a dictionary module? Thanks

Comment: martineau - there is no real format to the dictionary I found. It's just entries and definitions with no clear delimiters for a program to be able to pick out which are the terms and which are the definitions

Thanks BioGeek I'll take a look

Comment: @user1480135: If so, how are _you_ able to pick them out when you look at its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an array (list) of words. I want to loop though them and check if each one is in the English dictionary. If it is I want to increase a variable by 1.

If I understand you correctly, you can do that like this:

```
wordlist = ["foo", "bar", .....]
dictionary = …
words_in_dictionary = len([word for word in wordlist if word in dictionary])
```

> This is all very simple apart from the 'getting Python to read a dictionary' which I'm not sure about. I have found a .txt dictionary which I could use but the words are in there with definitions making it impossible to pick out the actual words.

You can either get a better dictionary (etc. unix' `/usr/share/dict/words`), or scrape the words from your dictionary, using e.g. `re`. If you post a portion of that dictionary, I can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Onse you have chosen an appropriate file to make your wordlist from, you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to keep track whether the words in your list appear in the English dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
wordlist = open('linuxwords.txt').read().splitlines()
d = defaultdict(bool)
for word in words:
    d[word] = word in wordlist

for word in d:
    print "Does the word '{0}' appear in the English dictionary: {1}".format(word, "yes" if d[word] else "no")
```

Result:

```
Does the word 'baz' appear in the English dictionary: no
Does the word 'foo' appear in the English dictionary: no
Does the word 'bar' appear in the English dictionary: yes
```